# Help needed for compressing file while moving to archive

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I have a list file and a source file present
in one directory (`/int/source/HR100`). 
So the contents of the source directory look like below.

```
Customer_Account_20211202.csv
Customer_Account.lst
```

The list file (`Customer_Account.lst`)
contains the name of the source file, i.e., `Customer_Account_20211202.csv`. 
Now I want to zip the source file
and move it to a destination directory (`/int/source/HR100/Archive`). 
I am able to achieve the movement using a one-liner Unix command
as shown below, but I can't figure out to zip **and** move the file. 
My preference is Gzip (`.gz`) format.

Code I am using:

```
xargs -a Customer_Account.lst mv -t /int/source/HR100/Archive
```

The above one-liner moves the code without compressing. 
I want a one-liner that will read the file from list,
compress and then move.

Comment: I am curious why you want a oneliner. In general, oneliners are not better than small scripts or even commands that span multiple lines. This is not meant to criticize, I am seriously curious about the need for a oneliner. You are also not the only one that asks for it, so there should be some benefit.

Comment: Do you want to keep `Customer_Account_20211202.csv` in the current directory and also put `Customer_Account_20211202.csv.gz` into the Archive directory?  Or do you want to get rid of `Customer_Account_20211202.csv` from the current directory? … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
a=$(cat Customer_Account.lst).gz; xargs -a Customer_Account.lst gzip -c >/int/source/HR100/Archive/$a
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one data file (which you call a “source file”),
then you don’t need `xargs`. 
[Romeo Ninov’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/681523/80216#681537), simplified for only one data file
and modified to actually do a move (`mv`), becomes

```
a=$(< Customer_Account.lst)  &&  gzip "$a"  &&  mv "$a.gz" /int/source/HR100/Archive
```

where `a=$(< Customer_Account.lst)` is just
a bash way of doing `a=$(cat Customer_Account.lst)`. 
So this reads the filename from `Customer_Account.lst`, zips the file,
and moves the zipped file to the Archive directory. 
We use `&&` to ensure that later steps are performed
only if earlier ones succeeded,
and we quote our variables because you should always do that.

But you call `Customer_Account.lst` a “list file”,
and you seem to want to use `xargs`. 
These facts suggest that you might some day
have multiple file names in `Customer_Account.lst`. 
So, consider this adaptation of your command:

```
xargs -a Customer_Account.lst sh -c 'for f; do gzip "$f"  &&  mv "$f.gz" /int/source/HR100/Archive; done' sh
```

Where your command uses `xargs` to run `mv`,
this one uses `xargs` to run `sh` (the shell). 
The shell is invoked with a one-line script that loops over the parameters,
and zips and moves each one.

This is fine if you have six to eight files. 
But it invokes `gzip` once for each file,
and it invokes `mv` once for each file. 
This is wasteful and may cause the command to take a long time
if you have hundreds of files. 
In that case, consider

```
xargs -a Customer_Account.lst bash -c 'gzip "$@"  &&  mv "${@/%/.gz}" /int/source/HR100/Archive' sh
```

This also runs the shell (specifically, bash)
with the list of filenames from the list file,
but it doesn’t do an explicit loop. 
Rather, it passes the list (`"$@"`) to `gzip`,
and then passes a modified version of the list to `mv`. 
The modification is done by `"${@/%/.gz}"`. 
`/%/.gz` is like `s/$/.gz/` in `sed`; it adds `.gz` to the end. 
And `"${@…}"` causes the substitution to be done
on every word in the argument list. 
(This functionality is present in bash,
but not all other POSIX-compliant shells.)